# ERROR - EF Core could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EF Core 3.1, C#, .net core

I am trying to query the database table AnglerResult and return stats for an angler like below:

| angler | # tournaments | wins | top 10 | in money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| angler 1 | 10 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| angler 2 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| angler 3 | 15 | 5 | 3 | 8 |

I don't know how to change the query so the "Count" sections are able to be "translated" as stated in the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (a.UserId), ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: AnglerResult ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ) ) .Count(y => y.FinishPlace == 1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Database table: AnglerResult

```
public int AnglerResultId { get; set; }
public int ResultId { get; set; }
public int SeasonId { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
public int TournamentId { get; set; }
public int FinishPlace { get; set; }
public int BFPlace { get; set; }
public decimal Weight { get; set; }
public decimal BFWeight { get; set; }
public decimal TotalPoints { get; set; }
public decimal Payout { get; set; }
```

Query:

```
Anglers = await _anglerResultRepo.GetTableContext()
                .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
                .Select(x => new AnglerDTO
                {
                    UserId = x.Key,
                    Name = x.Key,
                    State = "",
                    Tournaments = 0,
                    Wins = x.Count(y => y.FinishPlace == 1),
                    Top10 = x.Count(y => y.FinishPlace <= 10),
                    MoneyFinishes = x.Count(y => y.Payout > 0),
                    Likes = 0,
                    Views = 0
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tournaments)
                .Take(anglersToShow)
                .ToListAsync()
```

Which means it can't translate the "Count" parts of the query.  They need to be moved "up" in the query.  I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core 3.1 do not support such `Count`. You can emulate it by `Sum`

```cs
Anglers = await _anglerResultRepo.GetTableContext()
    .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
    .Select(x => new AnglerDTO
    {
        UserId = x.Key,
        Name = x.Key,
        State = "",
        Tournaments = 0,
        Wins = x.Sum(y => y.FinishPlace == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        Top10 = x.Sum(y => y.FinishPlace <= 10 ? 1 : 0),
        MoneyFinishes = x.Sum(y => y.Payout > 0 ? 1 : 0),
        Likes = 0,
        Views = 0
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tournaments)
    .Take(anglersToShow)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This works awesome!  I forgot to ask about tournaments.  I was just working around it by setting tournament count = 0.  How would you adjust it so it will also count the number of tournaments an angler fished?

Comment: I cannot help here, more information needed. Which tables is used? Better update question.

Comment: On line 8 of the code you submitted, it shows Tournaments = 0, I put that in there to get it to run. I need to perform some kind of Sum or Count or Group, etc. (I don't know) to be able to count how many tournaments the angler in question fished. The overall query looks at the AnglerResult table mentioned in original post and needs to calculate the # tournaments fished, tournament wins, tournament top 10s, and number of times in the money. I didn't know how to calculate the tournament wins so in original post I had it default to 0

Answer (score 0):

EF Core tries to translate your .Select statement into a SQL query which it is not able to.
Try to load the relevant Anglers from the database first and **then** map them to your DTO objects.

```
Anglers = await _anglerResultRepo.GetTableContext()
                .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tournaments)
                .Take(anglersToShow)
                .ToListAsync()
                .Select(x => new AnglerDTO
                {
                    UserId = x.Key,
                    Name = x.Key,
                    State = "",
                    Tournaments = 0,
                    Wins = x.Count(y => y.FinishPlace == 1),
                    Top10 = x.Count(y => y.FinishPlace <= 10),
                    MoneyFinishes = x.Count(y => y.Payout > 0),
                    Likes = 0,
                    Views = 0
                })
                .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Doesn't the "tolistasync" before the select for client-side processing?